# UIScrollView and Storyboards

Tags: ios, xcode

So i'm learning how to use scrollviews and i've got one working successfully.

When working with an xib file, it's easy to work with a scrollview as I can put a scrollview on the background/ workspace and set the size, how I want my labels and buttons to sit on top of it etc and then when i'm ready, move the whole thing onto my View.

The project i'm currently working on uses storyboards and so I don't have the ability to put the scrollview on the workspace and get my size and arrangement right.

Is there a workaround? What's the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: what's your question? it's not clear what you're not able to do here

Comment: Suggestion, don't use storyboards, they are really bad solution and they are only good for prototyping, not for production code.

Comment: Can I put the scrollview on the workspace somehow or is this there a common way that people get around this is the question i'm asking. How do people use scrollviews in storyboards if you can't play with the layout and arrangement of the full scrollview.

Comment: @ipinak Hes right, storyboards suck, bad. I only use them when creating test apps, but they are not compatible with <iOS 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add your scroll view to the view of one of the storyboard view controller's views, and then you can do the same things with it that you could do in a xib file. Also, even if your project uses storyboards, there's no reason that you can't have a xib file as well.